# Getting the typed word in a contentEditable Div from the cursor position

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, contenteditable

I have been reading nonstop on trying to get this done and found many answers that are close but no cigar. Here is my scenario:

I am trying to write a jQuery plugin to work like an intellisense editor for my users with keywords and datatypes and possible methods. This will feel like codeComplete in IDEs.

I need to get the partial word that is input so as to do a lookup in my keyword array and find matches to populate in a dropdown. Things work pretty well up until I found a few bugs.

I have a contentEditable DIV and need to get the cursor position. I have some code that was graciously provided in one of the previous answers I spoke of:

```
function getCursorPos() {
var cursorPos = 0;
if (window.getSelection) {
    var selObj = window.getSelection();
    var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
    cursorPos = findNode(selObj.anchorNode.parentNode.childNodes, selObj.anchorNode) + selObj.anchorOffset; /* FIXME the following works wrong in Opera when the document is longer than 32767 chars */
    //alert(cursorPos);
}
else if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    var bookmark = range.getBookmark(); /* FIXME the following works wrong when the document is longer than 65535 chars */
    cursorPos = bookmark.charCodeAt(2) - 11; /* Undocumented function [3] */
    //alert(cursorPos);
}
return cursorPos; }

function findNode(list, node) {
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] == node) {
        return i;
    }
}
return -1; }
```

The issue I am seeing is that the range + offset work for about 7-8 characters then spaces and other characters seems to stop cursor "progression" and then my whole getWord() function is thrown off.

Does anyone have any light to shed on this for me? Maybe I am not using code that helps in my specific situation. I have spent days now trying to understand Range and selectionRange objects and it is driving me nuts. :)

Comment: There's no such thing as `selectionRange` objects. That code sample looks generally a bit naive to me.

Comment: http://help.dottoro.com/ljikwsqs.php shows me the definition of it. Even has a link to Mozilla Developer page for it.

Comment: It's a term made up by dottoro. The Mozilla page it links to calls it `Selection`, as does every official reference, including the spec: http://html5.org/specs/dom-range.html#apis-for-the-browsing-context-selection:-the-selection-interface